# Is there a function similar to .format() from Python in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, web

Is there a way to write `('{0} {1}'.format(1, 2))` from Python in JavaScript ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436/2233706).

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return this.replace(/(\{\d+\})/g, function (a) {
        return args[+(a.substr(1, a.length - 2)) || 0];
    });
};
```

Use it like

```
var testString = 'some string {0}';
testString.format('formatting'); // result = 'some string formatting'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are [packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-format) providing that functionality and [libraries that include it](https://lodash.com/docs#template), but nothing built into JavaScript. If your format string is fixed and doesn’t use anything beyond simple interpolation, [“template literals”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) exist in ES6:

```
`${1} ${2}`
```

and the obvious ES5 version isn’t terrible:

```
1 + ' ' + 2
```